# Is there a free app to do AI text-to-speech?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, open-source, text-to-speech

I'm looking for a free way to do AI-powered "text to speech", so I can copy-paste an article or document and have it read to me.

I've tried `say` on the command line, but the lack of AI means it is much harder to comprehend. All of the non-AI TTS-libraries that I've found are also much harder to comprehend than the new generation of AI-powered TTS.

Specifically, the new AI-powered TTS services seem to understand some of the meaning and structure of the sentence that is being read, and so they provide better natural cadence. This alleviates stress on the listener to parse the meaning of what is being read out.

All of the apps I've come across so far have tried to get me to sign up for services that cost well in excess of $100 per year.

My best alternative at the moment is to write my own code to use an API such as the Google Cloud text-to-speech API, but even that will cost me around $0.12 to speak a typical 1300-word article.

Perhaps there is some kind of open-source software that works on Mac Silicon, that I can install to generate better speech from text?

Comment: Where did you search for such applications? There is at least one in the App Store for both macOS and iOS.

Comment: Do you not like the built-in TTS? It's not the world's best, but it's OK for occasional use.

Comment: @nohillside I looked in the app store, but the ones powered by AI all required paid subscriptions. Searching "AI TTS" produces only options with in-app purchases, and searching "AI text to speech" produces mostly speech-to-text instead of TTS apps. Perhaps I've missed something?

Comment: @Tetsujin I'd ideally like to use it a few times a day, so I can listen to news articles while doing chores. If it's not AI, I find myself straining to comprehend it. The difference is night and day if you compare Google's AI TTS demo to non-AI stuff.

Comment: I've also been on the hunt for something like this. Mac's built in TTS is pretty mediocre at best.